Databricks DataFrame to Google Drive (Sheets)
I need to send daily information which is extract from databricks and send to my Google Drive to be read in Google Sheets.

Data extraction in Databricks
Automatically send data to Google Sheets daily.

This is a way for other people who are not using Databricks to consume the data in other environments
Is there a way to do that?
I have this code, but it can't read the JSON file:
class Sender():

    def __init__(self):
        self.drive_service = None
        self.set_drive_service()
        self.set_drive_service("dbfs:/FileStore/credentials/credentials.json")

    def set_drive_service(self):
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file
        ('credentials.json')
        drive_service =  build('drive', 'v3', credentials = credentials)
        self.drive_service = drive_service
    
    def send_file(self, drive_folder_id, filepath):
        filename = filepath.split("/")[-1]

        file_metadata = {
            "name":filename,
            "parents": [drive_folder_id]
        }

        media = (self.drive_service
                    .files()
                    .create(body=file_metadata, media_body=filepath, fields="id")
                    .execute()
                    .print('id') 
                )
        return media.get("id")
    
def share_file(self, id_file, email):
    permission = {
        'type': 'user',
        'role': 'reader',
        'emailAddress': email,
        'sendNotificationEmail': False
    }    

    (self.drive_service
         .permissions()
         .create(fileId=id_file, body=permission, fields='id')
         .execute())


We have been using gspread https://pypi.org/project/gspread-pandas/ pandas for the same use case and it works perfectly. Also, what do you mean by it can;t read json file? Is there any error message you are getting?

what is the problem with reading a json file exactly ? - this should be easy to resolve, so what is the error that you are getting ?
